# Python: How to create a dialog Window prior to main app Windows

Tags: python, tkinter

Preface:

I have a Python ControlGPIO code with a working GUI (let us call it MainGUI).

I wish to have a dialog pop up window, prior to running MainGUI, in a way that the user can enable/ disable features in MainGUI. **BUT** MainGUI should start running only after dialog pop up window is closed.

My question is: How can I make a popup window that will postpone MainGUI untill it is closed?

Code below- `boot_windows` is my dialog pop up window (where all the enable/disable checkboxes will be ), BUT obviously does not postpone `App` as I need

```
root = Tk()
#output_gpioPins = [4,22,6,26]
#input_gpioPins = [3,21,5,27]
#ip = '192.168.2.112'

boot_windows = Toplevel(root)
text1 = ttk.Label(boot_windows, text="Hello World !!!")
text1.grid()

App = ContorlGPIOWindow(root, ip = '192.168.2.113', with_sf_bt=1, with_hw_bt=1, switch_names=['Light Kitchen','Light Room1', 'Window1', 'Window2'])

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do precisely what you want. Widgets exist in a tree-like structure. All windows except the root require a root window. The root window must be created first (which is why it's called the *root* window).

If you don't want the user to see it, you can hide it until it is ready to be displayed.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
boot_window = tk.Toplevel(...)
...
```

You can then call `root.deiconify()` when you are ready for it to be visible.

Another common solution is to use the root window for your dialog or splash screen or whatever, and then simply replace its contents with the real contents when you're ready.

As for how to wait for the popup... the root window has a method named `wait_window` which will enter the event loop and not return until the given window has been destroyed.

Here's an example of it's use:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MainGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello, world!")
        label.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

class Popup(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, root)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Click to continue...")
        label.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.destroy)
        button.pack(side="bottom")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    popup = Popup(root)
    root.wait_window(popup)

    main = MainGUI(root)
    main.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    root.deiconify()
    root.mainloop()
```